# Run Command/Service on first occasion of day

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager

I'm writing a simple Widget for Android which displays information which changes for every day. So the widget needs to be refreshed on midnight. The whole refreshing is implemented as a service and runs nicely, the problem is the invocation:

The only solution I found is to use the `AlarmManager` to a add an exact reoccurring timer on midnight each day. Then aquire a partial Wake-Lock, to make sure the device stays awake and run the code. This should work as expected but due to the usage of the wake lock, I am waking the device, so I am searching for a slimmer version:

There is no need to wake the device up on exact midnight, it is enough if I receive a timer event the first time the Device is up again on a new day. If the device is sleeping, nobody can look on the widget, so it is ok if the widget updates whenever the device is switched on again.

**In other words: How do I run a service on the first moment of a day when the device is not sleeping, thus preventing a wakeup? I still need the device to stay awake than for period of time.**

How can this bis done?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the AlarmManager to delay your invocation until the device wakes up anyway.
Then don't use a WakeLock in the.

Comment: How can you do this? Using `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` does not guarantee that my service is run on the first wakeup of a day.